# Cannot run program sdk path on android studio on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, sdk

I was using windows 10 and I have SDK stored on 
D:/android/android-sdk
and I switching to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and I insalled android studio 1.5 and I set the path of SDK 
/media/usr/partition-name/ANDROID/android-sdk

and I have a problem message
ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "/media/usr/partition-name/ANDROID/android-sdk"

Comment: that's because of admin privallages which you don't actually have to view this path. Use `sudo su` && nautilus` command and try again.

Comment: thanks , I will download the SDK secondly in "/usr/local/SDK" and ignoring the first SDK from windows

Answer (score 1):

You must download Android SDK for Linux, not for Windows ;-)

It's strange that Android Studio didn't ask you about installing SDK libs - it's integrated with this IDE.

Do not use `media` or `local` path. Please unpack it in your local directory: `home/your_name/`

If you have any question, please free to ask

Comment: Thanks a lot the problem I hava SDK that I used it on windows and I switched to ubuntu .. I thought that this version compitable with ubuntu but I knew that there a version to Windows and version to linux :) thanks